# Android Upload Response Message Not Expected

Tags: php, android, httpconnection

Here is my android code:

```
try
        {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile3) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile3 +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
    Log.d("serverResponseCode"+"", serverResponseCode +"");
    Log.d("serverResponseMessage", serverResponseMessage);

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Log.d("upload", ex.toString());//Exception handling
    }
```

And here is the php code:

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['profile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['profile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

The file can upload to server. However the response message is different as I expected.
From the Logcat, the `serverResponseCode is 200` and `serverResponseMessage is OK`
But from the php, I would like to get the message like `" XXX has been upload"`.
Does anyone know how to get the message??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer finally:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        String stringResponse = sb.toString();
        Log.d("response string:", stringResponse);
```